# How can I return following values?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on my project but I can't go on. My project should generate two code parts and convert these to two hashes. Thats all working. But now, I'd like to print the values out in the browser.

Thant is my unfinished code:

The Model:

```
namespace myapplication.test.Backend.Models
{
     public class CodeContainer
     {
          public string CodePartA { get; set; }
          public string CodePartB { get; set; }
          public string HashAB { get; set; }
          public string HashBA { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

The Class where I generate my codes and hashes:

```
namespace myapplication.test.Backend.Utilities
{
    public static class VerificationCodeUitillity
    {

        private static string GenerateHash(string input)
        {
           string hash = string.Empty; 
           using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
           {
                byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
            }

            hash = sBuilder.ToString();
        }

        return hash;
    }

    private static string GenerateCodePart(int lenght)
    {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        Random code = new Random();
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, lenght).Select(s => s[code.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }

    public static CodeContainer GeneratePVCode() 
    {
        CodeContainer result = new CodeContainer();
        result.CodePartA = GenerateCodePart(4);
        result.CodePartB = GenerateCodePart(4);
        result.HashAB = GenerateHash(result.CodePartA + result.CodePartB);
        result.HashBA = GenerateHash(result.CodePartB + result.CodePartA);

        return result;
    }

}
}
```

And here in my Demo Controller I'd like to return the values `CodePartA`, `CodePartB`, `HashAB` and `HashBA`.

```
 // GET api/demo/code
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("code")]
 public string Code()
 {
   //return values here
 }
```

Thanks for your help in advance!!

Cheers

Comment: I would start calling your GeneratePVCode, getting the result and trying to display the properties of the CodeContainer instance returned.

Comment: @steve can you make an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like that it should work:

```
    // GET api/demo/code
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("code")]
    public CodeContainer PVCodeGen()
    {
        return VerificationCodeUitillity.GeneratePVCode();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the IHttpActionResult Interface in api-methods.

```
// GET api/demo/code
[HttpGet]
[Route("code")]
public IHttpActionResult PVCodeGen()
{
    return this.Ok<CodeContainer>(VerificationCodeUitillity.GeneratePVCode());
}
```